# What does "back-slap" mean?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

What does *back-slap* mean in this sentence?

> Back-slap someone in Korea and they will be offended.

Comment: This question can be improved by citing sources you consulted before asking the question. Checking sources before posting and reporting what you found as part of your question is basic site etiquette.

Answer (score 3):

Literally, to slap someone on the back.  In the US, it's a gesture of conviviality or congratulations.

However, to call someone a "back-slapper" is something of an insult.  There's a strong connotation that the conviviality or congratulations is insincere.  Politicians are often called "back-slappers" (or "glad-handers", meaning a person prone to shaking a strangers' hands and grinning inanely, a similar dig).

Comment: +1 but a cite would be nice